# Use of the tilde, ~, and the dot in creating multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I am attempting to compose multiple plots using the following code:

```
plot(cyl ~., c('mpg', 'gear', 'carb'), data=mtcars)
```

In other words, by pressing the 'enter', or 'return' key, R will cycle through three plots with 'cyl' being the dependent variable and 'mpg' as the independent, then 'cyl' as the independent and 'gear' as the independent, etc.

Thank you for any constructive assistance you can offer.

Comment: Plots can be viewed in the "Plots" tab of Rstudio by clicking the left and right arrows or by pressing shortcut keyboard combinations (Ctrl+Alt+F11 or +F12). Isn't that enough?

Comment: For those voting to close due to *"unclear what you're asking"*, I think that is wrong here. I think the description of plot-flow is fine. One can argue that the OP has attempted no effort, but that is not the same as "not clear", and the *unclear* closure votes really should (imo) be accompanied by requests for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of an automatic function that cycles through plots *like that*. (There are statistical plots that default to cycling through them, such as [`plot.lm`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/plot.lm), but those are not the default/norm.)

You can iterate through them manually. Here's a method that allows much of `plot.formula` while giving you a little bit of control. Up front:

- New argument, `iterate = c(...)` which lists the fields you want to iterate over;
- New argument, `fakevar = "x"`, this is the variable you should place in the original formula that will be replaced on each iteration; if your data has an `x` in it, then change this value to a `character` of your variable name
- You can still use the `.` in the original formula, but it means what it is meant to mean: all other variables in the data.
- I use `locator(1)` to allow a "click on the plot to continue" mechanism; I'm sure there are others, this one is simple enough (and easy to replace).

The code:

```
myplot <- function(formula, ..., iterate, fakevar = "x",
                   verbose = TRUE, continuefunc = locator(1)) {
  continuefunc <- substitute(continuefunc)
  for (nm in iterate) {
    formula0 <- update.formula(formula,
                               as.formula(paste("~ . -", fakevar, "+", nm)))
    if (verbose) message(capture.output(formula0))
    plot(formula0, ...)
    eval(continuefunc)
  }
}

myplot(cyl ~ x, data=mtcars, iterate=c("mpg", "gear", "carb"))
# cyl ~ mpg
# cyl ~ gear
# cyl ~ carb
```

Explanation of parts:

- `substitute(...)` stores the "call" or intended call of the expression; with this, we can repeatedly call the function without trouble (try without this line to see what can happen, with multiple `iterate` variables)
- `update.formula` converts: `cyl ~ x` to `cyl ~ mpg` (for each iteration); the `~ .` puts everything on the RHS of the original formula into that dot, so it initially creates `cyl ~ x - x + mpg`, luckily R knows to optimize like-components, this reduces to `cyl ~ mpg`;
- `capture.output(formula0)` just pretty-printing things, for SA
- `plot(formula0, ..., data = data)` ... since I use the three dots, any other arguments you pass to `myplot` that are not one of `fake` or `iterate` are passed through to `plot`; e.g., `main="quux", pch=16`; this is an oft-forgotten trick when extending the capabilities of already-great functions: do as little as you need, pass the rest on to what is known to otherwise work well

Because of `continuefunc`, you can choose to:

- console-only continuation, with `myplot(..., continuefunc=readline('hello!'))`
- dump all without pause, such as reports (`knitr`/`rmarkdown`): `myplot(..., verbose=FALSE, continuefunc=0)` (0 or 1 or 912 or `c` or `TRUE` all work just fine, it's the lack-of-pause that is important)
- screen show: `myplot(..., continuefunc=Sys.sleep(3))`

Comment: This is a really nice in-depth answer. I learned new things!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using plotly:

```
library("plotly")
library("data.table")

mtCarsDT <- melt.data.table(data.table(mtcars), "cyl", c('mpg', 'gear', 'carb'))

plot_ly(mtCarsDT,
        x = ~cyl,
        y = ~value,
        frame = ~variable,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'markers',
        showlegend = F
)
```

also see [this](https://plot.ly/r/animations/).